# Validation of space in C syntax

Tags: c

How to write syntax that can validate allow only one space input from user? Example, if the user input 
"eat_food" it is VALID , when user enter "eat__food"(with 2 spaces) it would be INVALID..

and then show the appropriate error message to return right input?

Comment: Exactly one space or at most one space? Can there be multiple words, e.g. is "Halimi Abd Hadi" valid? And what did you try?

Comment: @Halimi you should show some effort!

Comment: (At a minimum, there should already be code in place to "read user input". It is hard to validate something that does not exist.)

Comment: sorry, i think it can use with strlen() function?

Answer (score 2):

This can be checked with `strstr()`:

```
#define IS_VALID_INPUT(input) !strstr(input, "  ")
```

This will result in `1` if there is not more than one space in the input, and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

After the following code, n is the number of spaces in the string str.
Then you can check it.

```
int i, n = 0;
for (i = 0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
    n = (str[i] == ' ') ? (n+1) : n;
```